# Webform archive and purge option in Drupal

Tags: drupal-8

I need to archive and purge the webform submission in Drupal site. There is already existing functionality in Drupal 8 for purging the submission automatically but I need to archive before deleting the results.How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you not deleting and then archiving?